# JOIN 3 tables for search

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables: Session, Film and Vendor

```
Session.FilmID
Film.VendorID
Vendor.VendorName
```

I want to include the VendarName in the search.

Here's what I have:

```
sql ="SELECT SessionID, Identifier, SessionType.SessionTypeName, Film.*, Vendor.*, 
CameraID, Date FROM Session "
sql = sql + "JOIN SessionType USING (SessionTypeID) "
sql = sql + "JOIN Film USING(FilmID) "
sql = sql + "JOIN Vendor ON Film.VendorID = Vendor.VendorID "
sql = sql + "WHERE Session.Identifier LIKE ('%" + search + "%') OR "
sql = sql + "Session.Notes LIKE('%" + search + "%') OR "
sql = sql + "SessionType.SessionTypeName LIKE ('%" + search + "%') "
sql = sql + "Film.Vendor.VendorName LIKE ('%" + search + "%') "
sql = sql + "ORDER BY Identifier,SessionType.SessionTypeName"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check out the last three lines you forgot to add conditional operator.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` not including any error message in the question? not showing any code at all? missing relevant information, like: what languages is that?

Comment: `Film.Vendor.VendorName` is a three level name. (is `film` a schema name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an 'OR' in your sql statement. Change this line:

```
sql = sql + "SessionType.SessionTypeName LIKE ('%" + search + "%') "
```

To:

```
sql = sql + "SessionType.SessionTypeName LIKE ('%" + search + "%') OR "
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. I'm getting the following error:

Comment: I should have been more specific. I'm getting the following error: near 'Film': syntax error

Comment: Brian, you were right! I had to make one additional change.  Thank you!